# Chrome SameSite Cookies

Tags: google-chrome, http, cookies, xss, samesite

if you work with SameSite cookie attribute and set it to strict and the server return a http error code like 404 or 500 an error message is displayed in chrome. So far so good. But if then the user refresh the page (F5 or reload button) while the 404 error message is displayed the cookies are not send with the GET request.
Is this the normal behavior? Tested it with FF 71 and the strict cookies are sent.

Comment: Do you have an example site that shows this behaviour?

Comment: Hi, no public site. But i can make a simple visual studio demo project. How can i sent it to you?